# Rendering ActiveStorage blobs from a JBuilder view in a Rails 6 API-only application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api, jbuilder, ruby-on-rails-6

I am building an API-only backend using Rails 6.0.0.rc1. My base controller extends `ApplicationController::API` and renders JBuilder views. My `Post` model has an ActionText rich text attribute called `content`. In order to render `Post.content` properly my JBuilder view renders an HTML partial. This works well except that any ActiveStorage images get the wrong domain name in their URLs (example.org).

```rb
# app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb

class Api::ApiController < ActionController::API
  include ActionView::Layouts
  layout 'api'

  before_action :set_default_response_format

  private

  def set_default_response_format
    request.format = :json
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/controllers/api/posts_controller.rb

class Api::PostsController < Api::ApiController
  def index
    @posts = Post.published
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/views/api/posts/index.json.jbuilder

json.posts @posts, partial: 'api/posts/post', as: :post
```

```rb
# app/views/api/posts/_post.json.jbuilder

json.extract! post,
              :id,
              :type,
              :slug,
              :path,
              :title,
              :excerpt

json.content render partial: 'api/posts/post-content.html.erb', locals: { post: post }
```

```rb
# app/views/api/posts/_post-content.html.erb

<%= post.content %>
```

I have tried various methods of changing the renderers default http_host value but none of them have worked. The only way I can fix this problem is to change my controller to inherit from `ApplicationController::Base` instead of `API`, which is not ideal. I'd prefer to selectively include whichever modules are required to make this work, but I haven't been able to figure out which ones this might be. I suspect that it might be the difference between `Rendering` and `ApiRendering`, but from what I can tell there's no way to mix those two.

**"Fix":**

```rb
# app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb

# We want to extend ActionController::API here
# but it's messing up the asset paths
class Api::ApiController < ActionController::Base
  # include ActionView::Layouts
  layout 'api'

  ...
end
```

Is there any way to fix the asset paths while extending `ApplicationController::API`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but `ActionController::API` is not intended to render HTML, it does not render  templates either. This line is not going to work for sure:

```
json.content render partial: 'api/posts/post-content.html.erb', locals: { post: post }
```

Why don't you just put `json.content` instead of rendering a template?